# Syntax error in single line

Tags: python-2.6

I'm getting a syntax error while trying to follow an infinite skills tutorial. If this is because I'm using a newer version than the instructor is, how can I keep using mine and prevent this in the future? This is the code

```
print ("hello,", end=' ') print (" world!")
```

I get a syntax error for the equality symbol.

Comment: Is it your first question on Stackoverflow? Welcome to the site; it looks like you are using Python3; you should add python3 as a tag for your question.

Comment: Also I'm not able to put the tag you posted it offers me qpython3

Comment: I don't think you're actually on Python 3. Try `import sys; print sys.version`.

Comment: Sorry; the exact tag is rather python-3.x if you actually use Python 3. I didn't want to put you in trouble but it can help to add such tags.

Comment: Okay so, I have edited the tag on my post to python 2.6 seeing that it's the version I'm using. My apologies everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't be doing that. python is all about whitespace and you shouldn't be putting two print statements on the same line. to accomplish what you want just make a new line (using the new line character `\n`) and combine the two statements. and you may not be running python 3 try removing the `end=' '` to see if that fixes the syntax error

```
print ("hello, \n world!")
```

you can also see what version of python you are running by this

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put a semicolon `;` between two statements in python:

```
print ("hello,", end=' '); print (" world!")
```

Comment: or use a new line, which is better.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why is like this when the instructors code was as I had posted. I'm very curious and eager it find out. He is using something before version 3.4

Comment: Wow, the most help I have ever gotten in the least amount of time on any forum since 1994. Amazing, thank you. Also, I agree with you concerning the whitespace and would have naturally write another print statement or else kept it simple print("Hello, world!") However, I'm glad I didn't just because it brought me to a new venue of knowledge. So I'm guessing that it's a version disparity then?

Comment: Also the instructor didn't use a semicolon. This is becoming very fascinating. I love this.

Comment: @Jake Cook; if you found my answer useful, don't forget to upvote it; I am just now trying to reach 1,000 points for my reputation and you may be the one who will make me reach it...

Comment: Okay it says I'm using version 2.6.6 I'm confused because I know I installed a 3x version and have been working out of the python34 directory. I'm so happy I wrote a script for getting the version. Should I add anything to it in order to find the version every time? This is so cool man thank you.

Comment: Okay, adding the new line character did put world on the next line. If m going to try everyone's suggestions and see what happens.